# pandas find two rolling max highs and calculate slope

Tags: python, pandas, stock

I'm looking for a way to find the two max highs in a rolling frame and calculate the slope to extrapolate a possible third high.

I have several problems with this :)
a) how to find a second high?
b) how to know the position of the two highs (for a simple slope :  slope = (MaxHigh2-MaxHigh1)/(PosMaxHigh2-PosMaxHigh1))?

I could, of course, do something like this. but I only work if high1 > high2 :)
and I would not have the highs of the same range.

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys  


df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")
df = df.ix[:10, ['High', 'Close' ]]

df['MAX_HIGH_3P'] = df['High'].rolling(window=3,center=False).max()
df['MAX_HIGH_5P'] = df['High'].rolling(window=5,center=False).max()

df['SLOPE'] = (df['MAX_HIGH_5P']-df['MAX_HIGH_3P'])/(5-3)

print(df.head(20).to_string())
```

Comment: "Two max heights" seems very ill-posed. You must define what it is in your context, because this make no general sense.

Comment: @B.M. Sorry. I Need the Highest and the Second highest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for a bit messy solution but I hope it helps:

first I define a function which takes as input numpy array, checks if at least 2 elements are not null, and then calculates slope (according to your formula - i think), looks like this:

```
def calc_slope(input_list):
    if sum(~np.isnan(x) for x in input_list) < 2:
        return np.NaN
    temp_list = input_list[:]
    max_value = np.nanmax(temp_list)
    max_index = np.where(input_list == max_value)[0][0]
    temp_list = np.delete(temp_list, max_index)
    second_max = np.nanmax(temp_list)
    second_max_index = np.where(input_list == second_max)[0][0]
    return (max_value - second_max)/(1.0*max_index-second_max_index)
```

in variable df I have this :

[image]

And you just have to apply rolling window to whatever you prefer, in example applied to "High":

```
df['High'].rolling(window=5, min_periods=2, center=False).apply(lambda x: calc_slope(x))
```

Final result looks like this:

[image]

You can also store it in another columns if you like:

```
df['High_slope'] = df['High'].rolling(window=5, min_periods=2, center=False).apply(lambda x: calc_slope(x))
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: exactly what i needed. no i need some time to understand what you've done!! thanks! E.